# Suggest a Rail-to-Rail OpAmp to Replace LM741

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have built a small amplifier circuit around two LM741 op-amps and have had to learn the hard way, as I usually do :), that the LM741 is not a rail-to-rail output op amp.

I have a 0-3.26V input which is to output -10V to +10V, and the circuit is being supplied by +/- 10V so I am not getting near the output needed.

Would someone be able to suggest a rail-to-rail dual-power (I'm assuming as I have +/- 10V output) that can easily replace the LM741.

By easily replace I mean pop one out and pop another in :), same connection diagram. Thanks a million for any help.

Comment: I agree with Jim. LM741 these days is like learning to drive on a Ford T. Sure you'll learn but why not take advantage of all the nice parts that are much betters in terms of Gain Bandwidth and Input impedance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the TS912, you can get it in DIP easily and it should fill your requirements.

The downside is that it isn't really pin-compatible, you'd have to make a couple changes.

Comment: Looks good thanks Clint, I have found TLV2770, would others think this would work, most of the information on datasheets goes over my head a little. It looks to be pin compatible if the SHDN, Shutdown pin is left NC.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the OP184

Its pin compatible, rail to rail input and outputs and guaranteed to work between +/- 1.5V to +/- 18V rails

Comment: From what I can see the OP184 is only available in surface mount SOIC, unfortunately I need a PDIP IC, would you have any other suggestions, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Newbie you should mention that in your question. Also there are converter prints that enables you to use a SOIC-8 but fits in a PDIP-8 socket.

Comment: Hi Jippie, yes I should have done, apologies, and thanks for information just having a look at SMT to Through Hole adaptors now, haven't seen them before, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no rail to rail op-amps that will output a voltage to either supply rail. It's a bit of marketing tosh - you might get a few to get within 10mV and there are plenty that'll do 50mV to either rail but if you need exactly +/- 10.000 volts increase your supply rails by a hundred milli volts.

I hope someone proves me wrong or at least finds one that gets to within a couple of milli volts of either rail under moderate loading conditions.

Comment: Hi Andy aka, that will do me fine, at the moment I'm only getting near 7.2V with the LM741 and its screwing things up a little. Have you ever heard of TLV2770

Comment: i have but I'm on android at moment  and can'tlook it up properly